# Automatically save after adding model to collection

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection `myCollection` to which I add models as follows:

```
myCollection.add({title: Romeo and Juliette, author: Shakespear});
```

Have can I now save this added model to the server? Backbone `Collection`s do not have a `save()` and I do not a reference to the added model to call `save` directly.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the **create** function on the collection to add a model and have it automatically saved to the server.

```
myCollection.create({title: Romeo and Juliette, author: Shakespeare});
```

Here's the [documentation on the create function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create).

Comment: Awesome. Wrote this functionality myself without noticing this.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the save method of your collection to the add event:

```
MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.bind('add', this.save, this)
    }
    save: function(){
        $.post(this.url, this.toJSON())
    }
})
```