# Backbone sync on collection add

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm adding an item to my backbone collection like this:

```
item = existingItem.clone()
myCollection.add(item)
```

I have overwritten sync in MyCollection like this:

```
sync: function() {
  console.log('sync is called')
}
```

however it seems that sync does not get called after the add - which executes successfully and fires an 'add' event. Am I missing something? or is this the correct behavior?

Comment: What you are looking for is create. Invoked on a collection, it will save the model and add it to the collection. See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create, it's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621091/automatically-save-after-adding-model-to-collection

Answer (score 4):

What you want is `myCollection.create(item)`.

Check the [Backbone Collection.create() doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create)

Answer (score 0):

Collection.create returns the model, but in some cases you might need access to the xhr object. In that case you can do:

```js
// add the model to the collection first
// so that model.url() will reference the collection's URL
myCollection.add(myModel)

// now save. this will trigger a POST to the collection URL
// save() returns the xhr so we can attach .done/.fail handlers
myModel.save()
.done(function(res) {
    console.log('it worked')
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log('it failed')
    // might be a good idea to remove the model from the collection
    // since it's not on the server
    myCollection.remove(myModel)
})
```